# ¿Como traer una consulta a la base de datos por Fechas?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

como dice el titulo estoy tratando de realizar una consulta por un rango de fechas a la base de datos 'Instalaciones', a la tabla 'PROYECTOF' al campo llamado 'Fecha' Pero no tengo mucha idea de como hacerlo ya q estoy empezando con php. mi codigo HTML es el siguiente:

```html
<td colspan="2">DESDE:<input type="date" id="fechai" style="border-radius:7px" ><br><br>HASTA:<input type="date" id="fechaf" onchange="submit" style="border-radius:6px" >
                        <input type="hidden" id="form_sent" name="form_sent" value="true">
                        <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Enviar">
                    </td>
```

y mi codigo PHP es el siguiente:

```html
 <?php 
                    if(isset($_POST ['form_sent']) && $_POST ['form_sent'] =="true"){
                        $fechai=$_POST['fechai'];
                        $fechaf= $_POST['fechaf'];
                       $consultaf = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM INSTALACIONES.PROYECTOF WHERE estado='FIN' OR estado='COT1' OR estado='OK1' AND fecha BETWEEN '$fechai' AND '$fechaf' ORDER BY FECHA DESC");
                          while($filaf = $consultaf->fetch_array())
                            {
                            $fechas[$a] = $filaf['fecha'];
                            $a++;
                        }    
                    }
                    ?>
```

Puede que el codigo PHP este mal pues me he guiado por varios tutoriales pero ninguno en concreto me ha dejado en claro como realizar la consulta.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El problema esta en donde? que resultado obtenes? que resultado queres?

Comment: Te faltan los atributos "name" en los inputs de las fechas. Si no en el php no podrás recoger los datos que envías a través del formulario.